# Would these traces cause a short?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

I recently designed a circuit board, but now I'm looking and I believe that once the diode and capacitor are connected, they might be shorted. Thank you for your feedback.

[image: capacitor]

[image: diode]

Comment: The photos that you have provided don't show enough context.  The 2nd photo is particularly bad - we can't see what connects where.  More appropriate might be a screen shot of your CAD package where the different layers are in different colors and displayed in transparent mode.  This allows us to see connectivity.

Comment: it's perfectly legal to have conductors between the pads of SMD parts.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, but I have to take another photo when i get home, but i thought this could be straight forward like this.  The diode(d1) and capacitor (c8) are both connected to +3.3, and then to ground. I just noticed the extra connections.

Comment: Are you referring to the thermal relief?

Comment: Yes, do you think that they could cause the diode or cap to be short circuited when connected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those "extra connections" you mention, are (as *Hearth* said in comments) part of a "[thermal relief pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_relief)".

I've cropped part of your photo showing the pads for `C8`, and marked the "extra connections" below. That thermal relief pad is probably the end of the capacitor connected to ground (we don't have enough context in the original photos to be sure, but it's typical of a ground plane).

The purpose of that type of pad is to *thermally separate* that solder pad from the large ground plane. It isn't needed on the other end of `C8`, as the other end connects to a normal track, not a large copper area:

[image: thermal relief pad showing copper "spokes"]

As explained in the Wikipedia article linked above, using thermal relief pads for component connections to large copper areas (e.g. ground / power planes) mean it's much easier to make a good solder joint, as you don't have to heat large copper areas up to soldering temperature.

> do you think that they could cause the diode or cap to be short circuited when connected?

They don't cause an *unintentional* short, since all of the "spokes" connect the same two points: (a) the solder pad (for that end of `C8`, in the example photo) and (b) the ground plane.

Or, if it's easier for you to think of it this way, those spokes are *intentional* shorts between points that should be connected *anyway* !

If it was a normal pad, not a "thermal relief pad", then there wouldn't be any gaps in the ground plane between those marked arrows, and there would be *more* copper joining that end of `C8` to the ground plane.

Comment: Thank You everyone for your input. I will try to make a clearer post next time. Thank you for the answer!